# Three-variable modular diophantine problem - what is the set of solutions? Is there any matrix ansatz meaningful?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

I'm rereading some older unfinished material again. I had the following problem which I still can only access by brute force and would like to -at least- understand more about an analytical access.

Consider $(r,s,t) \in \mathbb N^+ $ .
I ask whether for the following set of modular equations there is any option to find a general key to describe the set of solutions.
Consider
$$ \begin{array} {} 
 r&+s&+rs & \equiv 0 &\pmod t \\
 s&+t&+st & \equiv 0 &\pmod r \\
 t&+r&+tr & \equiv 0 &\pmod s \\
\end{array} \tag 1$$
To have this algebraically better(?) accessible I introduce $i,j,k \in \mathbb N^+$ and rewrite
$$ \begin{array} {} 
 r&+s&+rs & = i \cdot t \\
 s&+t&+st & = j \cdot r \\
 t&+r&+tr & = k \cdot s \\
\end{array} \tag 2$$
I hoped it would be possible to define some matrix-operation, but with modular arithmetic, which would help solve this (or at least reformulate in a more intuitive scheme), but I ran into too many problems so far - so this is one aspect of my question:

> Can the diophantine problem (1) be handled by matrix-operations, helpful for the finding of a general solution? (For instance: how to implement "modular matrix-inversion" if possible at all...)

I think I found correctly, that all of $(r,s,t)$ must be even. Beside this I did not really proceed algebraically and only have a set of solutions (which seems to be infinite) by enumerating solutions. If I begin with setting $r$ and $s$  then the set of solutions for the third unknown $t$ is finite or even empty.

> Can the set of solutions be given as parametrical description? (We have perhaps something similar to the sets of solutions of the Pell-problem)

*<sub>(Remark on background: if $(r+1,s+1,t+1)$ are all primes then $n=(r+1)(s+1)(t+1)$ should be a Carmichael number, btw. - this is also the origin for my fiddling)</sub>*

---

Beginning of set of solutions:

```
   r    s     t     fixing r,s, finding t. s is always been checked up to 2^15
 ==================
   2    2     2
   2    2     4
   2    2     8
   2    4    14
   2    8    26
   2   10    16     likely complete for r=2
  ------------------
   4    4     4
   4    4     8
   4    4    12
   4    4    24
   4    6    34
   4    8    44
   4   12    16
   4   12    64
   4   16    28
   4   24   124
   4   28    72     likely complete for r=4
  ------------------
   6    6     6
   6    6    12
   6    6    24
   6    6    48
   6   12    18
   6   12    30
   6   12    90
   6   16   118
   6   18    66
   6   22    40
   6   24   174
   6   30    72
   6   48   342
   6   54   192
   6   72   102     likely complete for r=6
  ------------------
   8    8     8
   8    8    16
   8    8    40
   8    8    80
   8   10    98
   8   16   152
   8   20   188
   8   28    52
   8   40   368
   8   80   728
   8   88   400     likely complete for r=8
  ------------------
  10   10    10
  10   10    20
  10   10    30
  10   10    40
  10   10    60
  10   10   120
  10   20   230
  10   30   340
  10   40    50
  10   40    90
  10   40   450
  10   50   140
  10   60   670
  10   70   260
  10  120  1330
  10  130   720     likely complete for r=10
  ------------------
  12   12    12
  12   12    24
  12   12    84
  12   12   168
  12   24    36
  12   24   108
  12   24   324
  12   28   376
  12   36    60
  12   36    96
  12   36   240
  12   40    76
  12   42   558
  12   60   396
  12   84  1104
  12   96   420
  12  132   192
  12  168  2196
  12  180  1176
  12  216   564
  12  276   360     likely complete for r=12
  ------------------
  14   14    14
  14   14    28
  14   14    56
  14   14   112
  14   14   224
  14   28   434
  14   56   854
  14  112  1694
  14  224  3374
  14  238  1792     likely complete for r=14
  ------------------
  16   16    16
  16   16    32
  16   16    48
  16   16    96
  16   16   144
  16   16   288
  16   24   424
  16   32    80
  16   32   112
  16   32   560
  16   40   232
  16   48    64
  16   48   208
  16   48   832
  16   56    88
  16   64   368
  16   72  1240
  16   96  1648
  16  112   480
  16  144  2464
  16  160   912
  16  288  4912
  16  304  2592
  16  352  1200
  16  432   736     likely complete for r=16
  ------------------
  18   18    18
  18   18    36
  18   18    72
  18   18    90
  18   18   180
  18   18   360
  18   36    54
  18   36   234
  18   36   702
  18   42   408
  18   48   186
  18   54   522
  18   72  1386
  18   90   108
  18   90   288
  18   90  1728
  18  108   414
  18  126  1206
  18  180  3438
  18  198   270
  18  198  1260
  18  270   468
  18  360  6858
  18  378  3600     likely complete for r=18
  ------------------
```

Comment: it is better to solve such an equation. $$q(r+s)+rs=it$$ $$q(s+t)+st=jr$$ $$q(r+t)+rt=ks$$  Then find out when $q=1$

Answer (score 1):

Above simultaneous equation shown below:

$\begin{array} {} 
 r&+s&+rs & = i \cdot t \\
 s&+t&+st & = j \cdot r \\
 t&+r&+tr & = k \cdot s \\
\end{array} \tag 1$

Equation, $(1)$ has parametric solution & is shown below:

$(i,j,k)=[(4m+1),(36m+5),(9m+2)]$

$(r,s,t)=(6m,12m,18m)$

for, $m=4$ we get:

$(r,s,t)=(24,48,72)$ &

$(i,j,k)=(17,149,38)$

Comment: Hmm, but what about one of the solutions from my above heuristical list, for instance $(r,s,t)=(4,4,8)$ or $(2,8,26)$ ? I don't see how the $(6m,12m,18m)$ recipe is applicable here? Or do you only mean, that that parametric recipe gives only a subset of the possible solutions?

Comment: ... just an appendix. For instance I found the the recipe $(r,s,t)=(r,(1+r)^2-1, (1+r)^3-1)$ which gives for constant $r$ and $(s,t)$ varying the largest possible $t$. which for instance gives for $r+1=3$ the other variables $s+1=3^2$ and $t+1=3^3$

Comment: @ Helms. You are right. the solution I gave is not a general one. Similar approach, for (r,s,t)=(4,4,8). We take, (i,j,k)=[(m+1),4m+3),(4m+3)] & (r,s,t)=(2m,2m,4m). For m=13 we get (i,j,k) =(14,55,55) & (r,s,t)=(26,26,52). For (r,s,t)=(2,8,26) you might need to take a different line of attack.

Comment: @Helms. For (r,s,t)=(2,8,26) Is good enough . You get, (i,j,k)=[(1),(r^4+5r^3+10r^2+10r+5),(r^2+2r+2)]

Comment: Yepp, that's it... I am searching a more general parametrizing, or another procedure at all, like you can find a set of, I think, three 2x2 matrices, which you can multiply iteratively to get *all* (infinitely many) solutions for a Pell-problem. At the moment I find my list with use of the divisors-function and happily for each fixed $r$ there are only finitely many pairsr $(s,t)$ possible. My ideal approach were, if there were some modular matrix-method at all to apply to eqn-system (1) or (2). But that is really tough fiddling, and I don't have even a promising first step...

Comment: ... (cntd) and well, I know your parametizing formula, it is known from the context of Carmichael numbers (which my ansatz finds as well) and thanks for pointing it out!