# Modular Eqn-system with $3$ unknowns $(r,s,t)$: formula for the maximal solution $t$ (given $r$)?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

*This question focuses an unmentioned detail arosen in an earlier question, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3404101/1714)*

I've recently reread an older sketch of mine and reconsidered the following set of modular equations in three even integer unknowns $(r,s,t) \in 2\mathbb N^+ $ .       :
$$ \begin{array} {} 
 r&+s&+rs & \equiv 0 &\pmod t \\
 s&+t&+st & \equiv 0 &\pmod r \\
 t&+r&+tr & \equiv 0 &\pmod s \\
\end{array} \tag 1$$

I've found empirically that given $r$ the range for the possible $t$ was upper-bounded by $t\le(r+1)^3-1 $ so $$t_\text{max}=(r+1)^3-1 \tag 2$$ and by this $s_{t_\text{max}}=(r+1)^2-1$.
(It is possible that some other $s$ itself is larger than $s_{t_\text{max}}$ but then $t_s$ is smaller than $t_\text{max}$).

I think I've had already an argument for this but don't find the notice and cannot reproduce it, so my earlier thinking might even have been wrong.

> Question: How can it be proved that the largest possible $t$ is indeed $t_\text{max}=(r+1)^3-1$?

---

Additional question: *can the proof be formed in a way that it generalizes to the analoguous system with four or more variables?*

---

**Example**: let $r=2$ ,then $t_\text{max}=26$ and $s_{t_\text{max}}=8$ form a solution. There is no larger $t$ possible when $r=2$.
However $s$ can be larger than $8$ but then $t_s$ reduces, and one possible solution is then $(r,s,t_s)=(2,10,16)$ . See some more examples in my linked earlier question.

***What I have seen so far*** which seems relevant is the following.
Assume with some given even $r$ such that $(r+1,s+1,t+1)=(R,R^2,R^3)$. 
Then from the first equation in (1) we get for the lhs
$$ \text{lhs}_1 = (r+1)\cdot (s+1) -1 = R \cdot R^2 -1 =R^3-1  $$
So for $t=R^3-1$ the *lhs* equals the *rhs* and the modulo-condition is trivially true.
From the third equation in (1) we get
$$ \text{lhs}_3 = (r+1)\cdot (t+1) -1 = R \cdot R^3 -1 =R^4-1 
$$
Since $s=R^2-1$ by assumption we ask whether the *lhs* is divisible by the *rhs* and because always $R^2-1 | R^4-1=(R^2-1)(R^2+1) $ the equation ins satisfied.

From the second equation in (1) we get
$$ \text{lhs}_2 = (s+1)\cdot (t+1) -1 = R^2 \cdot R^3 -1 =R^5-1 
$$
Since $r=R-1$ by assumption we ask whether the *lhs* is divisible by the *rhs* and because $R-1 | R^4-1 $the equation ins satisfied.

This does no more work, when $t+1=R^k$ with $k>3$. Let's look if $k=4$.
We could insert in Eq 1 in (1) the value $s+1=R^3$ and this becomes
$$ \text{lhs}_1=  R \cdot R^3 -1 = R^4 -1 
$$
so the congruence is satisfied. But using Eq. 3 with this we get
$$ \text{lhs}_3=  R \cdot R^4 -1 = R^5 -1 
$$
But now we have that $R^2-1 \not \mid R^5-1$ and the required congruence does not occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, I've found myself an answer.

We stay with writing $R,S,T$ as odd numbers, and $ r=R-1, s=S-1,t=T-1$ even numbers. In the case of $R,S,T$ being prime, the $r,s,t$ are the Euler's $\varphi()$ of that primes, and a triple of primes fulfilling the eqn-system are also constructing Carmichael-numbers $n=RST$ .

---

Assume $R$ is the smallest and $T$ the largest of the numbers, my question was, whether with a given $R$ the value $T=R^3$ is the maximal value for $T$ which allows a solution for the eqn-system, where then moreover $S=R^2$. 
From the given eqn-system
$$ \begin{array} {} 
 r&+s&+rs & \equiv 0 &\pmod t &\qquad & \small (1.1) \\
 s&+t&+st & \equiv 0 &\pmod r && \small(1.2)\\
 t&+r&+tr & \equiv 0 &\pmod s && \small(1.3)\\
\end{array} \tag 1$$
we reformulate for notational easiness with some positive integer $i,j,k$ reflecting the modularity-conditions
$$ \begin{array} {} 
 (r+1)&(s+1)&&-1 & = it  &\qquad & \small (2.1)  \\
 & (s+1)&(t+1)&-1 & = jr &\qquad & \small (2.2)    \\
 (r+1)&&(t+1)&-1 & = ks  &\qquad & \small (2.3)  \\
\end{array} \tag 2$$
and even more compact
$$ \begin{array} {} 
 R&S&& = iT &- (i-1)   &\qquad & \small (3.1)  \\
 & S&T& = jR &- (j-1)   &\qquad & \small (3.2)  \\
 R&&T& = kS &-(k-1)  &\qquad & \small (3.2)  \\
\end{array} \tag 3$$
We assume now, that $T$ has the maximal possible values and thus that $i=1$ in the first equation. We can then express $S$ as $S=T/R $ (note that so far nothing is required in regard of primeness of the $R,S,T$-values!)
We get then

$$ \begin{array} {} 
 S &= T/R &   &\qquad & \small (4.1)  \\
  T/R \cdot T &= jR &- (j-1) &\qquad & \small (4.2)   \\
 R \cdot T &= kT/R &-(k-1) &\qquad & \small (4.3)  \\
\end{array} \tag 4$$
The last equation (4.3) can be reformulated
$$ T(k/R-R) =  (k-1) \\
   T = { k-1 \over k/R-R} $$
finally arriving
$$   T= R{ k-1 \over k-R^2 }  \tag 5 $$
We see, that $k=R^2$ is a critical value, because the denominator vanishes and we have a singularity. To have positive finite values for all it is thus required that $k \ge R^2+1$ .
Assume $k = R^2+1$ then
$$   T= R{ R^2 \over 1 } = R^3  \tag {5.1} $$
If we increase $k$ to become $k=R^2+2$ then we have
$$   T= R{ R^2 +1\over 2 } \lt R^3  \tag {5.2} $$
and thus $T$ is smaller and has no more its maximal possible value. Of course if $k \to \infty$ we have 
$$  \lim_{k \to \infty} T= R{ 1 - 1/k \over 1-R^2/k } = R \lt R^3  \tag {5.3} $$
which is the minimal solution for $T$.

> So I've proved that indeed the maximal solution for $T$ is $T=R^3$.
>   **Formula 1** for fitting triples: $(R,S=R^2,T=R^3)$ give the triple with largest $T$ for a given $R$

As a preview on further discussions we can state now, that for a squarefree integer $n$ with three distinct primefactors $(R,S,T)$, such that $n=RST$ and morever being of the Carmichaeltype we have the following bounds for the primefactors:

> Corrolary 1: $ \sqrt[6]n \le R \lt S \lt T \le \sqrt n$ and thus the number of Carmichaelnumbers with a given smallest primefactor $R$ is bounded.

---

There is one more small pointe.

It is not obvious, that there are also solutions with $S>R^2$ and still $S<T$ such that then $S<T<R^3$. I looked for the maximal $S$ with the condition $R^2 \lt S<T$.

The following is induced by heuristics.

Empirically the maximal values for $s$ (depending on increasing $r$) occur if $r$ (from where also $R=r+1$) has the form $r= k(k+1)$ and thus $R=k^2+k+1$ or written differently $R=(k^3-1)/(k-1)$

Then based on the first handful of values of $k$ and $R$ we get the formula for the fitting triples:

> **Formula 2** for fitting triples  $(R,R^2<S,S<T<R^3)$
>   $$ \begin{array} {} R&= k^2+k+1 \\ 
>    S&= f(k) &= 2k^4 +3k^3+3k^2+2k+1 \\
>    T&= g(k) &= 2k^4 +5k^3+6k^2+3k+1 \end{array} \tag 6$$
>   which holds perfectly, for all tested $k<1000$ .
>   If for any other $R$ there exists a triple $R,R^2<S,S<T<T^3$ then $S$ is smaller than $f(k)$ where $k$ is calculated with a fractional value such that $R=k^2+k+1$

---

Of course, the solutions $(R,S=R^2,T=R^3)$  give composite $S$ and $T$ and so are not in the set of Carmichael-numbers. However, triples  $(k,R=k^2+k+1,S=f(k),T=g(k))$ *may* be all prime and thus define Carmichaelnumbers $n=RST$ but because they are *maximal* values (for given $R$) they define also somehow an upper bound for Carmichael numbers occuring (which  are named for having the property that $ \varphi(R),\varphi(S),\varphi(T) | n-1 = RST-1$ and similarly for any larger multitude of distinct primefactors)